# Unable to select an element c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an element with selenium and I can't select it with c#. I tried selecting it with XPath + CSS.

Code:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge']")));
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@id='recaptcha-audio-button']").Click();
```

[image]
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcGZC.png)

Comment: Have you tried to split it up in variables first and check in the debugger which results are wrong?

Comment: on the first time it is clicking but after i reopen the program and the google chrome driver when its clicking the audio recaptcha its saying: Your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now. For more details visit our help page